# pipenv option to mimic pip -f option

Tags: pip, package-managers, pipenv

In pip there is an `-f` option which does the following:

> `-f`, `--find-links` :    If a url or path to an html file, then parse for links to archives. If a local path or `file://` url that's a directory, then look for archives in the directory listing.

This is the preferred way of installing PyTorch, by setting the link to their overview website, e.g.:

```
pip3 install torch===1.3.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

For my virtual environments I use `pipenv` but I haven't found an option that does the same as `-f`. In the meantime, I can just look up the direct link to the package that is relevant for my system, but that is cumbersome.

Does pipenv provide a way to do the same thing as pip's -f?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I haven't found a work-around. What you can do, of course, is enabling the pipenv shell and doing what you must with pip, e.g.

```
pipenv shell
python -m pip install torch===1.3.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This will install torch in the pipenv environment *but* torch will not be added to the Pipfile (nor to the lock file).

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use environment variables recognised by pip to tweak its behaviour within `pipenv`'s execution. E.g.:

```
PIP_FIND_LINKS=https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html pipenv install torch==1.5.1+cu101
```

See:

- [Advanced Usage of Pipenv - Configuration With Environment Variables](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#configuration-with-environment-variables)
- [pip's User Guide - Environment Variables](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables)

Comment: Is this setting persisted in the pipfile or do you need to (re)set it each time you try to initialize from pipfile?

Comment: @claytond It won't persist in the `Pipfile` I believe. But the resulting package specification is properly persisted in `Pipfile.lock`. Please also consider end of the "Advanced Usage of Pipenv - Configuration With Environment Variables" section (see the link in the answer) for a recommendation on how to persist env vars on per-project basis.

Answer (score 5):

In the new version of pipenv (I tested with version 2020.11.15), you can install packages in this way:

```
pipenv install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.0%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The link can be found in the this page: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

This will be added to the Pipfile as well.

```
[packages]
torch = {file = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.0%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl"}
```

you need to manually check the link with your compute platform, os and python version.

Comment: `pipenv install torch==1.8.0+cu111 -i https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

doesn't work

Comment: @Shamoon Are you sure you tested with the newest version of pipenv?

Comment: @Shamoon I updated the answer. you are right, because the pytorch download page is not PyPI compatible.

Comment: Because this post does not include an alternative to the -f option anymore, I moved the accept back to my own answer. The whole point of -f is so that you do not have to manually find the exact link.