# How to install PyTorch with pipenv and save it to Pipfile and Pipfile.lock?

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, pipenv, torchvision

I’m currently using Pipenv to maintain the Python packages used in a specific project. Most of the downloads I’ve tried so far have worked as intended; that is, I enter `pipenv install [package]` and it installs the package into the virtual environment, then records the package information into both the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock.

However, I’m running into some problems installing PyTorch.

I’ve tried running `pipenv install torch`, but every time the locking step fails. Instead, I’ve tried forcing a download directly from the PyTorch website using

```
pipenv run pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

And it actually installs! If I run `pipenv graph` it displays both torch and torchvision with their dependencies. But one problem remains: neither torch nor torchvision are being saved into Pipfile and Pipfile.lock.

Any idea on how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 11):

When you use `pipenv run pip install <package>`, that skips the custom `pipenv` operations of updating the Pipfile and the Pipfile.lock. It is basically equivalent to doing a plain `pip install <package>` as if you did not have/use `pipenv`.

The only way to also update the Pipfile's is to use `pipenv install`.

Unfortunately, as I'm posting this, [`pipenv` does not have an equivalent for `pip`'s `-f/--find-links` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57647989/2745495). The best solution is to specify pytorch's "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/" URLs as an  [alternative package index](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#specifying-package-indexes), by adding it as a `[[source]]` in your Pipfile. See [this answer from Mohamad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68336073/2745495) and [this answer from Mitch McMabers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71181971/2745495) that describes how to do it. I recommend trying out those answers instead.

A less elegant and quite bad alternative is to manually find the correct torch wheel (`.whl`) links you need, which usually means looking for the correct link from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html. Then, create/modify the Pipfile with the [specific package versions](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#specifying-versions-of-a-package) and URLs to the wheels:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"

[packages]
torch = {version = "==1.6.0", file = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0-cp38-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl"}
torchvision = {version = "==0.7.0", file = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl"}
```

Then just do normal `pipenv install`.

You can confirm the installation with `pipenv install --verbose`:

```
Collecting torch==1.6.0
  ...
  Looking up "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0-cp38-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl" in the cache
  Current age based on date: 8
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): download.pytorch.org:443
  https://download.pytorch.org:443 "GET /whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0-cp38-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  ...
  Added torch==1.6.0 from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0-cp38-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#egg=torch 
...
Successfully installed torch-1.6.0

Collecting torchvision==0.7.0
  ...
  Looking up "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl" in the cache
  Current age based on date: 8
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): download.pytorch.org:443
  https://download.pytorch.org:443 "GET /whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  ...
  Added torchvision==0.7.0 from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#egg=torchvision
...
Successfully installed torchvision-0.7.0
```

This also adds entries to Pipfile.lock:

```
"torch": {
    "file": "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0-cp38-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl",
    "hashes": [
        ...
    ],
    "index": "pypi",
    "version": "==1.6.0"
},
"torchvision": {
    "file": "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl",
    "hashes": [
        ...
    ],
    "index": "pypi",
    "version": "==0.7.0"
}
```

With that, you now have a Pipfile and Pipfile.lock that you can check-in/commit to version control and track/manage as you develop your application.

Instead of manually editing the Pipfile, you can also do it from the command line:

```
(temp) $ pipenv install --verbose "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl"
Installing https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl...
...
Adding torchvision to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded
```

That should also add an entry to the Pipfile:

```
[packages]
...
torchvision = {file = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl"}
```

Of course, this all depends on finding out which wheel you actually need. This can be done by first using a plain `pip install <package>` with the `-f`/`--find-links` option targeting the https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html URL, then checking which wheel it used.

1. First, let's get the correct `.whl` file with `pip install`

   ```
   $ pipenv run pip install --verbose torchvision==0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
   Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
   ...
   Collecting torchvision==0.7.0
     Downloading torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (387 kB)
   ...
   ```
2. Remove `pip install`-ed things from the virtual environment

   ```
   $ pipenv clean
   ```
3. Repeat installation but using `pipenv install`

   ```
   $ pipenv install --verbose "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchvision-0.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl"
   ```

   - Just combine "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/" + `.whl` filename from step 1

It might seem a bit backwards using `pip install` first then copying it over to `pipenv`, but the objective here is to let `pipenv` update the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock (to support deterministic builds) and to "document" your env for version control.

Comment: **Ouch that's a lot of work for doing something the wrong way. It's a GREAT answer which clearly took hours of effort to come up with, but it's a really bad and incorrect way of doing it, hehe.** Look at the other answers, which tell how to add pytorch as a repository in pipenv so that it can find the torch package, lol. That's the proper way! :D

Comment: @MitchMcMabers Yes, I've already upvoted the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68336073/2745495). I've also already considered deleting my answer, but I found that it can be an alternative in case adding the pytorch url to `[[source]]` doesn't work, because apparently it's not a 100% foolproof solution. See https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4422#issuecomment-673510838 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/69743918/2745495. I also read somewhere it _might_ not install the correct dependencies on the Pipfile. I don't know what you expect me to do from your rather humiliating comment.

Comment: Adding the repo to pipenv is the correct way and is basically what pip already has built-in. The inability to find packages happens when people use the wrong version of Python. For example, if I create a pipenv (virtualenv) with Python 3.10, and try to add the repo to Pipfile, I will get "Could not find a version that satisfies requirement". Lowering to Python 3.9 allows pipenv to find the library. This is because Torch itself doesn't support Python 3.10 yet. The 2nd issue you linked is the same thing, he tried to install Torchtext 0.81 on Python 3.7 but only 3.7m packages exist .

Comment: If I wasn't clear enough (for anyone that reads this in the future): **Both people you linked to tried to install Torch while they were using the wrong versions of Python. Torch doesn't exist for the versions of Python they were using. Had nothing to do with Pipenv.** And I really think your answer is great. It's very in-depth even though it's totally pointless to do it that way. But it's a cool answer about internal tricks and techniques that can be used. Just ... not necessary. :D

Comment: @MitchMcMabers Edited to point to yours and Mohamad's answers.

Comment: Sounds great, and thanks again for your detailed post. It was interesting to learn that it's possible to directly link to a .whl file. I might need that someday! :)

Answer (score 5):

you can install it by adding the PyTorch source to your pip file as following:

```
[[source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
torch = {index = "pytorch",version = "==1.9.0"}
torchvision = {index ="pytorch", version= "==0.10.0"}
torchaudio = {index ="pytorch", version= "==0.9.0"}

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

And then run `pipenv install`

Note: The index refers to the source name.

you can do that with any similar cases:
ex: Install pytorch-geometric:

```
[[source]]
name = "pytorch-geometric"
url = "https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.9.0+cu111.html"
verify_ssl = true
[packages]

torch-scatter = {index= "pytorch-geometric", version= "==2.0.7"}
torch-sparse = {index= "pytorch-geometric", version= "==0.6.10"}
torch-cluster = {index= "pytorch-geometric", version= "==1.5.9"}
torch-geometric = {index= "pytorch-geometric", version= "==1.3.2"}
```

Comment: **This technique is the correct one and it's documented here: pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#specifying-package-indexes** However, you should always use `verify_ssl = true`, so I've edited that part to ensure that people are taught the correct way to add a repository to pipenv. Also, people can go to pytorch.org and select "Stable, Pip, Python, CUDA 11.3" (or whatever is the latest CUDA you may be using), and then the command textbox will reveal the repo URL for the latest CUDA toolkit. You MUST remove the HTML filename because that's the pip-specific repo. **See my answer for details.**

Comment: Absolutely unacceptable that the community hasn't fixed this by making the command work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

*(**Notice:** [The most up-to-date version of this post is always at the Pipenv project site, since I can't maintain the same edits in multiple places forever.](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4961#issuecomment-1045679643))*

---

**This technique is the correct one and it's documented here:**

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#specifying-package-indexes

Basically, you add a new "source repository" to your Pipfile. And you should always use `verify_ssl = true` for extra security when possible.

Anyway, there's a shortcut to adding a custom repository without editing the pipfile. The `--extra-index-url` shortcut says "Add this PEP 503-standard repo URL":

- Version that uses CUDA Toolkit 11.3, with GPU acceleration (this toolkit is required by NVIDIA Ampere (RTX 30x0) GPUs and newer):

```
pipenv install --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/ "torch==1.10.1+cu113"
```

- Version that uses CUDA Toolkit 10.2, with GPU acceleration:

```
pipenv install --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/ "torch==1.10.1+cu102"
```

- Version that uses CPU instead:

```
pipenv install --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/ "torch==1.10.1+cpu"
```

#### **Now you may notice something: There's no ".html" in my repo filenames.**

That's because the repos with a HTML filename (such as https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html) are NON-STANDARD repos that ONLY pip understands.

*You CANNOT use those URLs in Pipenv.*

Pipenv uses PEP 503 standardized repos. Torch publishes those at the URLs WITHOUT ".html" filenames. So remove the filename to get the proper repo URLs for Pipenv usage.

This fact is documented here, when Torch's team decided to finally publish PEP 503 repos: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25639#issuecomment-861707149

#### **You may notice something else: I always specify a version with `+cpu` or `+cu113` or whatever.**

This is NECESSARY, because otherwise Pipenv doesn't know which version to install and won't get GPU acceleration. The "architecture" (GPU vs CPU vs different CUDA toolkits) is baked into the version number. It's literally what Torch decided to do, and the ONLY correct way to download them is to specify the exact version and architecture (such as `+cu113`) you want.

#### **If you want to figure out the URL to the correct repos/versions in the future, do as follows:**

Go to pytorch.org and select "Stable, Pip, Python, CUDA 11.3" (or whatever is the latest CUDA you may be using), and then the command textbox will reveal the repo URL for the latest CUDA toolkit. You MUST then remove the HTML filename because that's the pip-specific repo.

Visit the resulting URL, such as https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/, and navigate into the desired library folder. Then search for the version you wanted, and be sure to specify its FULL version specifier, such as `1.10.1+cu113`.

Oh and sometimes, the Torch team forgets to upload the latest version to the PEP 503 repo, such as right now, where `1.10.2` is available but only in the non-standard pip-style repo. That's why you should always visit the PEP 503 repo to see the latest version they've uploaded into that repo. (I would love if they completely stop providing the old-school pip-repo at all, since pip supports PEP 503 too, so they should focus on the standards-compliant repo...)

See my examples above for perfect installation instructions for the current versions as of this writing.

#### **One final note: ALWAYS RESPECT THE TORCH PYTHON VERSIONS.**

The packages will have names such as "cp37", "cp38", "cp39". As of this writing, the highest version they have created is for Python 3.9. There's no Python 3.10 version of Torch.

Therefore, it helps to install Pyenv and specify an exact Python version in your Pipenv via `pipenv install --python=3.9` to ensure that you have the latest version that Torch supports and not anything "too new/unsupported". :)

Answer (score 0):

Gino Mempin's solution worked for me (I only had to change the url slightly to "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/", so add "cpu/"). Then I tried the following and it worked as well and is easier imo and you don't need to specify the version.

Pipfile:

```
...
[[source]]
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/"
verify_ssl = false
name = "pytorch"

[packages]
torch = {index = "pytorch", version = "*"}
...
```

Then just `pipenv update`.

This is for the cpu version of pytorch; there is another folder "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/" which I assume would work similarly for the cuda version.